# Tcl: How to do a callback accross namespace borders?

Tags: tcl

Consider a library structured like this:

```
package provide ::mylib 1.0

namespace eval ::mylib {
  namespace export f
  proc f { action } {
    # pass action around
    g $action
  }
  proc g { action } {
    eval $action
  }
}
```

If I try to use it like this, it won't work:

```
....
namespace eval ::user {
    set x 10
    ::mylib::f { puts $x }
}
```

The reason is that $x is not known in mylib. I can fix it like this:

```
namespace eval ::user {
  set x 10
  ::mylib::f { puts $::user::x }
}
```

This works, but qualifying each variable in the argument to ::mylib::f is awkward. Another possibility is to wrap the code inside another namespace eval:

```
namespace eval ::user {
    set x 10
    ::mylib::f { namespace eval { puts $x } }
}
```

Better, but still ugly. If it were Ruby or Perl, I would simply pass a closure to ::mylib::f. What is the best practice in Tcl?

BTW, I'm currently on Tcl 8.3, but hope to have the possibility to upgrade to a newer version soon, so solution in terms of 8.3 AND more recent versions are wellcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr version: `namespace code`

The `namespace code` command is intended for this situation. You pass it the script that you want to be encapsulated, and it hands you back a version that has magic in it so that it handles being called from anywhere. Here's how you might use it.

```
namespace eval ::user {
    variable x 10
    ::mylib::f [namespace code { puts $x }]
}
```

Internally, it uses `namespace inscope` to do this. You're recommended to not use that directly; `namespace code` is the convenient way of doing this.

Note that it even works if the callback site passes arguments to it, so long as that site is doing:

```
eval $callback [list "the argument is this"]
```

(In fact, in 8.3 the `eval` isn't necessary because of a *gross* hack in `unknown`, but please do it the way I recommend above because we took that hack out in later versions. It was pretty awful.)

Comment: Everything here should work from 8.0 onwards; there were no significant changes at all to namespaces from 8.0 through 8.4…

Comment: It works great! I just don't understand: If the callback site passes arguments, how can the block access these arguments?

Comment: To comment my own comment: I think your trick to pass arguments from the callback side to the evaluated block, works only if the callback variable contains nothing but a procedure call, right?